# Quickbooks Enterprise Hosted integration

Tags: quickbooks

I see a lot of integration w Quickbooks Online, but i need Enterprise - Hosted <-> Salesforce. Anyone has experience with this? thanks!

Comment: When you say "Enterprise - Hosted" are you referring to Quickbooks on a local server? If so, this can be done using SOAP or REST custom solution to your enterprise network. Look in the App Exchange for vendors if you don't want to build your own solution. If I'm not mistaken, it can also be done using Dataloader. It just depends on how frequently you want to sync between the two systems.

Comment: Yes on a server that client vpns into. Sync needs to be automated and frequent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe QuickBooks Hosted is just QuickBooks Desktop (and QuickBooks Enterprise) on a Citrix-esque server. So, you need to find a tool that will integrate with QuickBooks Desktop/Enterprise, then see if you can install the application on the Server your QB instance is running on.

So, I'd suggest you first check with the company providing the QB hosting and ask them if you can install a small application on that server.

If the answer is yes, you can look at the solutions provided by Avankia, Interweave, and a few others. Be warned that these solutions were developed a number of years ago and can be a bit heavy to setup.

If none of this works, and integration is an absolute must, you might have to move your QB to self-hosted.

Or, if cloud is more important, move to QuickBooks Online or Xero with an accountant.